# How to get the mean of first values in arrays in matrix in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector, mean

If I have a square matrix of arrays such as:

[1,2], [2,3]

[5,9], [1,4]

And I want to get the mean of the first values in the arrays of each row such:

1.5

3

Is this possible in Matlab?
I've used the mean(matrix, 2) command to do this with a matrix of single values, but I'm not sure how to extend this to deal with the arrays.

Comment: Is your matrix a 3D matrix with those values serving as slices? Your notation is confusing.  Please use actual MATLAB syntax to express your matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Get the first elements in all arrays of matrix, then call  `mean` function

```
mean(matrix(:,:,1))
```

maybe you need to reshape before call `mean`

```
a = matrix(:,:,1); 
mean(a(:))
```

Comment: Though this better answers the question, this is all speculation. We have no insight on the actual shape or format of the matrix, so this answer may not be correct when the OP decides to edit his question... though I suspect he will never come back.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply mean function inside mean function to get the total mean value of the 2D array at index 1. You can do similary with array at index 2. Consider the following snapshot.
[image]

Comment: It's more useful to have actual text rather than a snapshot.

Comment: That's not the result that he wants

Answer (score 0):

After staring at your problem for a long time, it looks like your input is a 3D matrix where each row of your formatting corresponds to a 2D matrix slice.  Therefore, in proper MATLAB syntax, your matrix is actually:

```
M = cat(3, [1,2; 2,3], [5,9; 1,4]);
```

We thus get:

```
>> M = cat(3, [1,2; 2,3], [5,9; 1,4])

M(:,:,1) =

     1     2
     2     3


M(:,:,2) =

     5     9
     1     4
```

The first slice is the matrix `[1,2; 2,3]` and the second slice is `[5,9; 1,4]`.  From what it looks like, you would like the mean of only the first column of every slice and return this as a single vector of values.  Therefore, use the `mean` function and index into the first column for all rows and slices.  This will unfortunately become a singleton 3D array so you'll need to squeeze out the singleton dimensions.

Without further ado:

```
O = squeeze(mean(M(:,1,:)))
```

We thus get:

```
>> O = squeeze(mean(M(:,1,:)))

O =

    1.5000
    3.0000
```